# How to implement CAS in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to know how to implement compare_and_swap in c++11.
Here's what I tried:

```
template<typename T>
T compare_and_swap(atomic<T>& reg,T newVal )
{
    bool success = false;
    T oldVal;
    do
    {
        oldVal = reg.load();
        success = reg.compare_exchange_weak(oldVal,newVal);
    }while(!success);
    return oldVal;
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: You should try to ask in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: compare_exchange already does the swap, you don't need your wrapper at all.

Comment: @Mat negative, compare_exchange would certainly add code lines in some situation.<e.g.>situation that need semantics of compare_and_swap  many times

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. compare_exchange *is* compare_and_swap, just a different name. If you don't want the loop, use the strong variant.

Comment: @Mat tks dude. I didn't understant compare_exchange clearly.

Comment: This `compare_and_swap` isn't an equivalent of standard  `compare_exchange_strong`. The later one can fail and return false, while the former loops until it succeeds. This is an equivalent of  `exchange`. In fact it's a valid implementation of `exchange` for a CPU without atomic exchange instruction. But it's slightly inefficient: you shouldn't `load()` inside the loop because you get the updated value from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
//untested code
template<typename T>
T compare_and_swap(atomic<T>& reg,T newVal )
{
     oldVal = atomic_load(reg);
     while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&reg, &oldVal, newVal));
     return oldVal;
}
```

The compare exchange function will update the oldval value if it fails. Therefore there is no need repeating this.

As you can see I prefer to use the explicit atomic operations. This is because the full one's aren't always implemented. As is explained by Herb Sutter [here](https://youtu.be/CmxkPChOcvw?t=33m53s)(the rest of the video might also interest you:) ).

As a posibbly unnecessary afterthought I would like to warn against using this function with non [trivially copyable](https://youtu.be/CmxkPChOcvw?t=33m53s) types. Or 'normal' pointers. Shared pointers are in general okay:).